# It's possible to make typedef or define char pointer with malloc?

Tags: c

What I want to do is have string256 act like: `char* s = (char*)malloc(256);`

```
string256 s; /* this is what Iam trying to do */


char* s = (char*) malloc(256); /* this is how it looks in real life */
```

and use it

```
strncpy(s, "__test__", 9)

s[9] = 0x00;
```

P.s. typedef or define or function code length doesn't matter. only matters string256 s;
I won't forget to use free or error checking;

full code will look like this :

```
 __Free_String_if_Flag_true __Zero_Memory __check_for_Errors __string_256 string256
```

and use it

```
string256 s;
```

Comment: Don't do it! You have to remember to free all your `string256`s if you do manage to figure out how to do it that way. It's just a maintenance nightmare!

Comment: Why do you want to hide the malloc() call? How will the string be freed? Will you write `free(s)`, or do you want that call to be hidden as well?

Comment: Disregarding all of these (wise IMHO) suggestions, you _can_ do what you are asking with #defines (see below).  Your next questions though should pursue, _why is it not a good idea?_

Comment: Such macros are not a good idea.

Comment: And what are those prefixes exactly?

Comment: @self macros - functions

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

A typedef defines a name for a type.  `char* s = (char*) malloc(256);` is a variable declaration, not a type.

You could probably achieve something similar with macros, but I would strongly advise against it (for a start, it would obscure the fact that a `free` would be necessary at some point.)

Comment: It is not a statement; it is a declaration with an initialiser.

Comment: @wildplasser: Indeed it is ;)

Comment: You are giving serious attention to only half of the question.  It is indeed _possible_ to use a #define.  OP can determine later if using a  #define _should_ be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a typedef of a char array:

```
typedef char char256[256];

char256 s ;
s[255] = '\0' ;
```

The variable will stop existing when out of scope, but you can make it global if you want it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

As for the part of your question asking about ***...or define...***:
In short - ***Yes you can***:  (partially taking exception with some of the other comments/answers)
***However***, I also agree with those answers that suggest it may not be in the best form to use #defines for such calls. (but you can do it)

***Edited*** (removed ";" from macro)

```
#define string256(s) char *(s) = malloc(256)  
//...  
string256(s);  //use parenethesis
/...  
strcpy(s, "yes I can");
```

***s*** now contains "yes I can" ***and*** is null terminated (`strcpy()` does that)

Do not forget to also create a macro for `free(...);`

Comment: +1 this is good but still not what i want p.s.you forgot \ after string256(s) :)

Comment: Don't put a semicolon in a macro define; defining a free would be redundant.

Comment: So char* s; and string256(s); it's same as char* s = (char*)malloc(256);

Comment: @user3321220 - you do not need to (and should not) cast the return of _malloc()_.  Also, regarding the "\" (you actually mean '\0' I assume)  In the example I provided, it is not shown explicitly, but it is placed by using `strcpy()`.  Regarding _still not what I want_.  Well, Although I have no real insight into your mind, it seems to be exactly what you asked for.  Be more explicit.

Comment: Sure sure..., those expert with years of experience are probably just dumb. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE11-C.+Do+not+conclude+macro+definitions+with+a+semicolon

Comment: @self - good link on macros, thanks.  I removed the `;` in my post.  I did not consider that it could actually in some situations change the program flow.  I am surprised that nobody addressed the bigger issue on this question though... Its not recommended to _change syntax via macro substitution. It makes the program unintelligible to all but the perpetrator._ ***[Here](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CCodingStandard.html#mnames)***

Comment: @ryyker I mean #define string(s) \ char* s = (char*)malloc(256) but this is dosn't matter. thanks for asnwer

Comment: @self I believe you think I'm newbie? in C , but just I want you to know: I have expience with C, C++, VB, C#, PHP, JS, Delphi. ofcourse VB,C#,C++ and delphi I left behind me long time ago and all answers posted here I already know, I though it will be more pro asnwer, but what I got is for rookie nad p.s. don't forget free or you know why macro bad. So I still think here is someone who could give me very goood! answer not for newbies with all bad things let me deal by myself.